# Display result contained in let declaration Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am attempting to display the result of `await this.contract.mint(amount, {value: this.state.tokenPrice.mul(amount)})`. I would like to see what it outputs.

```
  async mintTokens(amount: number): Promise<void>
  {
    try {
      let showResult = await this.contract.mint(amount, {value: this.state.tokenPrice.mul(amount)});
      this.setState({
        successMessage: showResult,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setError(e);
    }
  }
```

The code has error `Type 'ContractTransaction' is not assignable to type 'string'.` and I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe read this first: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html

Comment: `showResult` is not a string like `successMessage` expects. You could stringify the object or pick certain information out of it, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just stringify the object:

```
...
      this.setState({
        successMessage: JSON.stringify(showResult),
      });
...
```